# Does the Full HTML format allow all tags, and is there an Input Filter without built-in restrictions?

Tags: 7, input-formats

Does the *Full HTML* format allow all tags, without any restrictions at all? I am not quite sure, but it seems some input filters have other restrictions in addition to what their options dialogs allow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Full Html by default allows all tags (hence the name). To see how yours is currently setup, go to /admin/config/content/formats/full_html. Under Enabled Filters, see if you have "Limit Allowed HTML Tags" checked. If you do, you will also have a vertical tab at the bottom of the form labeled "Limit Allowed HTML Tags", on which you can configure which tags are enabled.

If you want to add your own format, you can do so on /admin/config/content/formats and configure it however you would like.